# Generate HTML from HTML template in python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, jinja2, template-engine

I want to design my own HTML template with tags like [`JSP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) or [`Jade`](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/) and then pass data from python to it and let it generate full html page.

I don't want to construct document at python side like with [`DOM`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). Only data goes to page and page tempalte decides, how data lays out.

I don't want to serve resulting pages with HTTP, only generate HTML files.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I found Jinja2, but I has strange [boilerplate requirements](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/). For example, they want me to create environment with

```
env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication', 'templates'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
)
```

while saying that package `yourapplication` not found. If I remove `loader` parameter, it complains on line

```
template = env.get_template('mytemplate.html')
```

saying

```
no loader for this environment specified
```

Can I just read template from disk and populate it with variables, without extra things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `FileSystemLoader`:

```
import os
import glob
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

# Create the jinja2 environment.
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(current_directory))

# Find all files with the j2 extension in the current directory
templates = glob.glob('*.j2') 

def render_template(filename):
    return env.get_template(filename).render(
        foo='Hello',
        bar='World'
    )

for f in templates:
    rendered_string = render_template(f)
    print(rendered_string)
```

`example.j2`:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p><i>{{ foo }}</i></p>
        <p><b>{{ bar }}</b></p>
    </body>
</html>
```